# Exception for rewriting every php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|zip|xml|json|html|txt)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

This works perfectly, but I want to except the one file I use as a GET endpoint.
I tried:

```
RewriteRule /assets/get_endpoint\.php - [L,QSA]
```

But that didn't work... I'm still getting rerouted to the "index.php".
AND the php file will definitely consist of GET parameters as well.
e.g.

```
www.example.com/assets/get_endpoint.php?date=2019-12-21&location=Paris
```

The .htaccess only consists of those two lines ( and the third ).
This should be really easy but I can't figure it out. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?assets/get_endpoint\.php$ - [END]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|zip|xml|json|html|txt)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php [END]
```

I also made a few other optimizations once on it :-)

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, and the explanation and everything - I really appreciate it. But, it doesn't seem to solve my issue... I'm still getting my index.php.
I restarted apache (XAMPP on Mac) and tried different browsers to avoid browser caching. What could I be doing wrong...

Comment: Where did you implement those rules and what is the exact URL requested which you would expect _not_ to get rewritten to `/index.php` ?

Comment: I've implemented everything in my .htaccess file.
```www.example.com/assets/get_endpoint.php?date=2019-12-21&location=Paris``` but of course with alternating parameters.

Comment: Above rules definitely should work... Maybe you are looking at cached results? Test using a fresh anonymous browser tab please. If nothing helps you will need to start debugging. For that enable "rewrite logging" and monitor the detailed steps your rewriting engine logs. You will start to understand what is going on inside the rewriting module if you make a request...

Comment: I thought I could rule out browser caching...  And I do think too that those rules should work... but even now several days later they're not working, so it's definitely not the browser cache.

Comment: I couldn't find out what the issue was - I did found out however there seems to be a misconfiguration of my virtual host. Thank you so much for your help. I do have to fix this issue first - maybe this will fit with your solution then.

Comment: Would you mind sharing _what_ miss configuration and _why_ you failed to find out the issue? Rewrite logging allows a very close insight into what is going on. So the short statement "wasn't able to find out" is quite disappointing... Debugging is about finding out. Not about running away from issues.

Comment: You're absolutely right - but so far I only know that I can change my .htaccess as much as I want - even keep it empty and everything still works - and I am sure that's why your rules didn't work - or none of them... I can't just figure out what I'm doing wrong since the vhost config points to the right directory and the right htaccess - and I tried, new browser, new user, etc... it works everywhere so there's no caching issue.
Thank you for your help, but I think the main problem is me for not finding the right way.

Comment: So I finally solved my faulty configuration - and your rule was right all the time - thank you so much!